# Starting Embedded Android

Tags: android, android-studio, embedded

I have some experience in developing mobile applications in Android Studio.
I have to develop an android application on Embedded Android Board.
I have some questions regarding embedded Android system app development. Is the application development in Embedded android same as mobile application development ?
Can I develop Embedded Android apps using Android Studio and debug them similar to mobile android apps ?
I used Kotlin for mobile android apps. Can I use Kotlin for embedded android apps also or is Java must ?
Do  the embedded android support USB camera and keyboard like windows instead of touch screen ?

The boards that I have come across are Odroid and Tinker. Is it okay to use either of these or are there more options ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can install any app by ADB Shell to check application compatibility. About supporting usb camera and other devices you must ask Tech Support of the product you use and/or check on Product Support forums.